# Use spread operator to combine an unknown number of objects

Tags: javascript

Here's what I'm trying to do.

Suppose I've got an array of objects like so:
    `const arr = [ {a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}, {e:5, f:6}  ];`

I'm trying to convert this into one object, that looks like this:
    `const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};`

I know that I can accomplish this with the spread operator like this:
    `const obj = {...arr[0], ...arr[1], ...arr[2]};`

But what if I don't know how many objects are in `arr`? It seems like there must be a way to loop through each object in the array and "spread" them into one object, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...arr)`

Comment: And there it is. I should have come here sooner lol. Thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

Spread it into assign like this:

```js
const arr = [ {a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}, {e:5, f:6}  ];
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr);
console.log(obj); // {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}
```

Comment: Isn't this just @4castle's comment?  Seems a bit cheap

Comment: I didn't see it tbf, feel free to vote down. This is pretty basic stuff

Comment: @Tibrogargan It isn't cheap. Even if he did take it from a comment, it is not against the policy. If there is an already posted answer (not comment), that would be a problem.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What does being against policy have to do with being cheap?

Comment: @Zinc this is the best answer - and since people may not look at comments it should be an answer, but yeah, maybe as community tbh

Answer (score 2):

A `reduce` would work nicely here:

```js
const arr = [ {a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}, {e:5, f:6}  ];

const obj = arr.reduce((combo, item) => {
    return {...combo, ...item};
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```